# Making all items of observable array an observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have a little demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/3030/), and I want the list to update when I change the **name** property of an item of the array. As I understand I have to make all of the items as observables. How can I do it?

```
 this.allItems = ko.observableArray([{name:"Fries"}, {name:"Eggs Benedict"}, {name:"Ham"}, {name:"Cheese"}]);
```

Comment: You'll have to use the `mapping` plugin: `ko.mapping.fromJS([{...}])` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

You define a method that returns an object with an observable `name` property:

```
var makeNameObservable = function(obj) {
  return {
    name: ko.observable(obj.name)
  };
};
```

You can then use `map` to transform your array:

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([ /* ... */ ].map(makeNameObservable));
```

Usually, in knockout applications, these objects are called viewmodels and instantiated using a constructor. For example:

```
 var Food = function(name) {
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
 };

 Food.fromObj = function(obj) {
   return new Food(obj.name);
 };

 // Elsewhere:
 var myFoods = [ { name: "Fries" } ].map(Food.fromObj);
```